# clang 3.6 fold expression left/right

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, c++17

I'm trying the fold expression with clang 3.6 '--std=c++1z', but something I don't quite get. The function that I'm testing is:

```
auto minus = [](auto... args) { return (args - ...); };
...
std::cout << minus(10, 3, 2) << std::endl;
```

according to [n4191](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4191.html), I'm expecting it expands as a left fold to

```
(10 - 3) - 2
```

which gives result 5, however, the result is 9, which seems to be a right fold expansion, i.e.

```
10 - (3 - 2)
```

Am I missing anything or mis-understand n4191?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

n4191 was revised by [n4295](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4295.html). According to that, an expression of the form `(e op ...)` is a *unary right fold*, and that is expanded as: `E1 op (... op (EN-1 op EN))`, i.e. as a right fold expansion.

This does seem to be the reverse of what n4191 stated in terms of the fold direction. Clang 3.6 implements the n4295 proposal, as shown [here](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

`... - args` would be a *unary left fold* and expand in the direction you want.